# Use Limits to calculate slope of the tangent

Tags: limits, tangent-line, slope

Use limits to calculate the slope of the tangent to the curve $y=\frac1x$ at $x=a$. I need to write an equation for the tangent to $y=\frac1x$ at $x=4$.

I think I understand the basics of the question and using the formula

$$\lim_
{a\to0}\frac {f(x+a)-f(x)}{a} $$

when I worked it out the way I think I suppose to I got

$\frac1{x(a+x)} $ then $\frac1{2(a+2)} \to \frac1{2(0+2)} \to \frac14
$

So is my limit $1/4$? How should my answer be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f (x+h)-f (x)}h&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac1{x+h}-\frac1x}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-h}{h(x+h)x}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-1}{(x+h)x}\\
&=\frac{-1}{x^2}
\end{align}

Comment: so with x=a would I swap the x with a in the formula? for example 

lim             f(a+h)-f(a)
h->0                  h

and when writing an equation for y=1/x at x=4 that would be my answer?

Comment: Yes,you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\lim_{h->0}\frac{\frac{1}{a+h}-\frac{1}{a}}{h}$$ for $$h\ne 0,a\neq 0$$

Comment: so would that become -1/a^2 and -1/16? for x=4?